# Python descriptors with old-style classes

Tags: python, class, descriptor

I tried to google something about it. Why do non-data descriptors work with old-style classes?

Docs say that they should not:
"[Note that descriptors are only invoked for new style objects or classes (ones that subclass `object()` or `type()`).](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#descriptors)".

```
class Descriptor(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 1

    def __get__(self, obj, cls=None):
        return self.x


class A:
    x = Descriptor()

a = A()
a.x

>>> 1
```

Thanks.

Comment: Because 'Descriptor' is a new-style class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right to question the documentation. I've tried looking through [CPython sources](http://svn.python.org/view/python/) to find an explanation, but be warned: I'm no expert.

From my understanding, attribute lookup and descriptor `__get__` invocation occurs in [`instance_getattr2`](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Objects/classobject.c?revision=81029&view=markup) (chosen extracts):

```
v = class_lookup(inst->in_class, name, &klass);
if (v != NULL) {
    f = TP_DESCR_GET(v->ob_type);
    if (f != NULL) {
        PyObject *w = f(v, (PyObject *)inst, (PyObject *)(inst->in_class));
    }
}
```

So either I am missing something, or nothing in the implementation requires a new-style object (which contradicts the documentation).

For the record, I tried recompiling Python to restrict descriptor invocation to new style classes objects, but it actually brought up a gigantic mess. I learned in the process that class methods themselves are implemented as descriptors: this is the mechanism used to return bound or unbound method objects depending on the usage. For example:

```
>>> class A:
...     def foo():
...         pass
...
>>> A.foo.__get__(None, A)
<unbound method A.foo>
>>> A.foo.__get__(A(), A)
<bound method A.foo of <__main__.A instance at 0x000000000229CC48>>
```

As a result, **it seems that preventing descriptor invocation for attributes of old-style objects or classes would also prevent method calls on them**, at least with CPython implementation.

Once again, I'm no expert and this is the first time I dive into Python implementation, so I could very well be wrong. I've filed [an issue](http://bugs.python.org/issue18047) to try to clarify this.

Comment: Thanks for the investigation, it is really helpful.

Comment: I edited my answer after a debugging session in CPython: I had the wrong functions involved, but the result stays the same.

Comment: In Python all functions (including methods) are non-data descriptors. So they should act like you say.

Comment: But I still do have one question. Why `__get__` does not work if a `Descriptor` is an old-style class? I think that if an attribute or method of old-style (or new-style) class is subinstance of `object` (all functions are), the interpreter  trying to execute `__get__`.

Comment: Note that in python3 there unbound methods are gone. They are simply function attributes of classes. @alexvassel I believe the limitation is not on the class using the descriptor(`A` in your example), but on the class that implements the descriptor(`Descriptor`). If `Descriptor` is an old-style class, then `__get/set/del__` are *not* considered like special-methods, hence they aren't called. When the `Descriptor` class inherits `object` then those methods *are* considered special.

Comment: The documentation is backwards/misleading: "... descriptors are only invoked on new style ..." is trying to say "descriptor protocol *methods* (`__get__`, `__set__`, and `__del__`) are only invoked on new style ...". So the *descriptor* need to be new-style, not the class using the descriptor.