# Why does setter behave differently in new-style class and old-style class

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, new-style-class

Using python 2.7, suppose I have a `Test` class with the new-style class syntax defined below.

```
class Test(object):
  def __init__(self):
    self._a = 5

  @property
  def a(self):
    return self._a

  @a.setter
  def a(self, val):
    self._a = val

t = Test()
print t.a
t.a = 4
print t.a
print t._a
```

Run the code above will print `5,4,4` which is the desired behavior.
However, if I change the first line of the code above to `class Test:` then the results becomes `5,4,5`.

Does anyone know what causes this difference in output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descriptors are *not guaranteed to be invoked for old-style classes*. From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/howto/descriptor.html#definition-and-introduction):

> The default behavior for attribute access is to get, set, or delete
>   the attribute from an object’s dictionary. For instance, `a.x` has a
>   lookup chain starting with `a.__dict__['x']`, then
>   `type(a).__dict__['x']`, and continuing through the base classes of
>   `type(a)` excluding metaclasses. If the looked-up value is an object
>   defining one of the descriptor methods, then Python may override the
>   default behavior and invoke the descriptor method instead. Where this
>   occurs in the precedence chain depends on which descriptor methods
>   were defined. **Note that descriptors are only invoked for new style
>   objects or classes (a class is new style if it inherits from object or
>   type).**

So, what's going on here is that `Test.a.__set__` is never being invoked, you are simply adding an `a` attribute to `t`:

```
In [8]: class Test:
    ...:   def __init__(self):
    ...:     self._a = 5
    ...:
    ...:   @property
    ...:   def a(self):
    ...:     return self._a
    ...:
    ...:   @a.setter
    ...:   def a(self, val):
    ...:     self._a = val
    ...:

In [9]: t = Test()

In [10]: vars(t)
Out[10]: {'_a': 5}

In [11]: t.a
Out[11]: 5

In [12]: t._a
Out[12]: 5

In [13]: t.a = 100

In [14]: t.a
Out[14]: 100

In [15]: t._a
Out[15]: 5

In [16]: vars(t)
Out[16]: {'_a': 5, 'a': 100}
```

What should really surprise you is *why does the `T.a.__get__` work here at all*?

And the answer to that is that in Python 2.2, old-style classes were reimplemented to use descriptors, and that is an implementation detail that should not be relied on. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16712002/python-descriptors-with-old-style-classes) question, and the linked [issue](https://bugs.python.org/issue18047).

Bottom line, if you are using descriptors, you should only be using them with new-style classes.

Note, if I do use a new-style class, it works as it should:

```
In [17]: class Test(object):
    ...:   def __init__(self):
    ...:     self._a = 5
    ...:
    ...:   @property
    ...:   def a(self):
    ...:     return self._a
    ...:
    ...:   @a.setter
    ...:   def a(self, val):
    ...:     self._a = val
    ...:

In [18]: t = Test()

In [19]: vars(t)
Out[19]: {'_a': 5}

In [20]: t.a = 100

In [21]: t.a
Out[21]: 100

In [22]: t._a
Out[22]: 100

In [23]: vars(t)
Out[23]: {'_a': 100}
```